# Understanding Setting JQuery Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Understanding Setting JQuery Variables

Recently I was introduced to setting a JQuery variable as seen below via assistance I was looking for on another question I had on StackOverflow. You can create an input field via simply calling upon a variable and it also appears that the anchor variable defines styles too!

```
var clicked = $('.clicked');
var ul = clicked.children('ul');
var input = $('<input />', {
    type: 'text',
    class: 'rename',
    value: 'New Folder',
    focusout: function() {
        $(this).siblings('a').html($(this).val()).show();
        $(this).remove();
        $(anchor).parent().removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
var anchor = $('<a>', {
    href: '#',
    css: {
        display: 'none'
    }
});
ul.prepend($('<li>').append([input.select(), anchor]));
```

I believe I understand how to modify and recreate the above snippet, the only aspect I don't actually understand is the setting of the styles. Upon my research, I haven't yet found anything alike this method and I'm hoping I can find more of an understanding via posting a question.

My aim is to understand and use more frequently with my next target being to create a select option field with all the options calling for `.selectBoxIt()` at the end.

### **UPDATE**

I'm not entirely sure if this is the *best* way to achieve this however I've come up with a solution thanks to answers to as how to create a select option list;

```
var select = $('<select />');
var options = [
    {val : 1, text: '3 DAYS'},
    {val : 2, text: '10 DAYS'},
    {val : 3, text: '30 DAYS'},
    {val : 4, text: '60 DAYS'}
];
$('.hello').prepend(select);
$(options).each(function() {
    select.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
});

// Because we are appending at a later date
// for the .selectBoxIt(); to work...
$(".hello select").selectBoxIt();
```

Comment: Why don't you add a inline style to the input tag itself.. also you can put all the styles in a class and use that class as well

Comment: @Reddy this is not so much regarding how to set styles but more to how this method works. If I can understand and recreate using to create an input field then by calling `.selectBoxIt()` this modifies via a JQuery plugin.

Comment: I'd love to understand, add features of which are currently not present and whatnot, however I do not know where to begin as my research is not bringing up anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start here http://api.jquery.com/jquery/ and scroll down to the section on creating new elements.

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to jQuery() can accept a plain
>   object consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed
>   to the .attr() method.

Comment: Thank you @etoisarobot. How come my posted snippet works however there is no apparent closing tags? Does JQuery run through this, understand and add to the end?

Comment: Additionally, in a select option list, how would I create several options?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6602002/2199267) seems useful however can it be done in style of my above snippet?

Comment: @TimMarshall When you're just creating a single element, it just needs the element tag, it doesn't need the full HTML.

Comment: @TimMarshall Options are not attributes of the element, you can't add them there. You need to create the `<option>` elements seperately and then `.append()` them to the `<select>`

Comment: @etoisarobot I've just updated my question, what would you say to this method?

Comment: @TimMarshall since you are learning right now, don't worry too hard about _**best**_ see if you can get it working first. As you learn more you'll go back and realize "oh hey I can do this like ________"